# Missing-this-annot together with jQuery each()

Tags: flowtype

Pretty basic usage of jQuery that seems not easy to give a proper type in Flow inline?

```
jQuery(`.someclass`).each(function(j, el) { ... }
```

Any tips? I've tried to add `/*this: Object*/` or such, but seems not enough. Obviously I cannot change the order of arguments in an external library function like this, even tho Flow wants `this` to always be the first argument.

I already have `declare var jQuery: any` at top of file, btw. Do I need to be more specific?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried leveraging [flow-typed](https://github.com/flow-typed/flow-typed)? jquery is already typed there and seems the `each` function you're looking for is also there https://github.com/flow-typed/flow-typed/blob/master/definitions/npm/jquery_v3.x.x/flow_v0.104.x-/jquery_v3.x.x.js#L3257

Comment: I can try, but I can't find anything in that file related to `this`. Hopeless keyword to search for, haha.

Comment: There's no way to disable this check?

Comment: Yep, warnings can be ignored with `// $FlowIssue[missing-this-annot]` :)